# Joining multiple SQL tables with table names in row of table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SQLite and I'm not sure if this can be done. Consider I have these table:

```
======>Table: Total_Table

_id    Name   Ingredients

0     "A"     "table_a"<br>
1     "B"     "table_b"

=====>Table: table_a

 _id    Name

 0      "a_1" <br>
 1      "a_2"

=====>Table: table_b

_id    Name
0      "a_1" <br>
```

The tables referenced in the rows of `Total_Table` have a different number of rows and are created as rows in `Total_Table` are added.

At the moment, I need to structure a query which will return rows from `Total_Table`.

But will search through the entries of the `Ingredients` tables.

For example, if I am looking for all rows in `Total_Table` which have **a_1** in their `Ingredients` table, it would return rows `0,1` from `Total_Table`.

Currently, I am doing this by querying all rows of `Total_Table`, then iterating through those entries and querying each table individually, forming an array as I go.

This is pretty bad since the tables I am looking through are relatively large, and hurts performance.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find this easier with a slightly different database schema. SQLite is a relational database, so let's try to store things accordingly. Basically, we'll have 3 tables, one for `Total_Table`, one for your ingredients, and a table to map which ingredients to which instance in the `Total_Table`.

Logically, it will look like this:

```
Table: Total_Table

_id    Name
0      "A"
1      "B"

Table: Ingredients

_id    Name

0      "a_1"
1      "a_2"

Table: Total_Ingredients

total_id  ingredient_id
0         0
0         1
1         0
```

The benefits here are many. First, you don't need to create any tables at runtime. You'll need exactly 3 tables, regardless of how many `Total_Table` entries you have. Second, it's easy to query. Third, you're not duplicating the name `a_1` anywhere in the revised schema (this is called [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

Then, your query would look like this. Note that in the sample data, `a_1` has an id of 0, which we'll use for querying purposes.

```
select _id, Name from Total_Table where id in 
  (select total_id from Total_Ingredients where ingredient_id = 0)
```

**Update:** Your other query is pretty similar if I understand correctly. So, you want the recipes which have some or all of a given ingredients. Suppose your subset includes ids 1, 5 and 7 for this example, the only change is to use an `in` clause.

```
select _id, Name from Total_Table where id in 
  (select distinct total_id from Total_Ingredients where ingredient_id in (1,5,7))
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. Each of the entries in total table correspond to a list of ingredients per entry. I can't simply combine all the tables because the entries of each ingredient tables are different from the entries in the total table.

Comment: Do the ingredients vary in their structure? Are you storing different values in the database for each ingredient lists? Otherwise, it seems like you have a list of totals, and a list of ingredients; each total can have many ingredients, and ingredients can be in more than 1 total. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct. For example, say In totals, there is a row for a simple recipe. This recipe has a name and a list of ingredients, which is not in the same row. The list of ingredients is in a separate table. Totals will be a big list of recipe, each of which will have a separate list of ingredients. When i search for these recipes by ingredient, I need to go over all table entries in total and each separate recipe list.

Comment: Actually, I think I understand your way, and its much better than what I was thinking. I was just a bit confused. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help! The schema above is pretty much a classic example of a many-to-many relationship in a database. A recipe can have many ingredients, and any given ingredient can appear in many recipes.

Comment: To go a bit further, could you also point me in the direction of finding a subset of ingredients within the same recipe? Say I have Bacon, Lettuce, and Strawberries, and I want recipes that contain all or just some of these. Would you also know how to do this using this scheme?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14416/discussion-between-batman-and-wsanville)

Answer (score 0):

Try combining your tables as one (preferably a View) and then do a look up. Or run your query as below:

```
String name = "bla bla bla";

"SELECT DISTINCT _id FROM Total_Table WHERE _id IN
     ((SELECT _id FROM table_a WHERE Name='" + name + "') UNION ALL
      (SELECT _id FROM table_b WHERE Name='" + name + "'))"
```